# Texture baking in blender 2.80

Tags: texture-baking

I need to preface this with "I am not an artist or in any way know what I am doing".

Summary:
* [solved] Work out how to have all the materials bake to one Image
* Work out what bake settings I need to get base-color and Alpha information into the output image

---

Detail:
I am trying to optimize my avatar for VRChat using blender 2.80. 
In particular, I am trying to reduce the materials from around 14 separate materials down to one texture/material.
With 2.79, I would have created a texture-atlas using a plugin that no-longer exists, and then selected to bake textures (as per https://youtu.be/0cSesu_zkQQ?t=943).

With 2.80; I understand that the plugin is no-longer necessary, and have successfully made what appears to be a valid UV map, but I lack an understanding of how to do the bake I want to the destination I want.
I have switched the renderer to cycles as per many notes, but I can not see the option for "texture" in the Bake-Type drop-down.
(I have options for Combined, Ambient Occlusion, Shadow, Normal, UV, Roughness, Emit, Environment, Diffuse, Glossy, Transmission ans Subsurface)

While poking and proding, I did once get a baked image, but the result was both dark, and over-writing all the existing textures, with each part splashed where the new UV would put it on the original texture rather than in a new texture.

Ideally what I am trying to achieve shouldn't tamper with the colors being placed in the new texture, just transcribe from 14 textures to 1 texture, via the conversion between the UV maps.

My apologies up-front for lack of information, please help me to improve my question so that I can get to an answer.

---

Further Progress:
I have found for straight colour transfer, I am looking for the Diffuse option with lighting options turned off. This is progress.

~~I am still having issues with the many-to-one stage.~~

~~I can make two copies of the mesh, one with the old UV and one with the new, and use Selected to Active; but the model has several close-spaced layers to the mesh used on shape-keys, and this results in a very speckled baked texture.~~

---

Progress as-of 20190707
I have achieved single-model baking by adding the *same* output block to to the shader graphs of all the materials and making sure that it really is selected.  I did find that if I just pasted the block in, despite showing up as the selected item in the graph, in the properties for the material, the base-colour field would still show that the input was selected. clicking the output block again fixed this.

Apparently Diffuse is not quite what I want as none of the alpha information was transferred to the output texture
Combined results in a very dark image due to unwanted application of the Shader;
The Manual suggests that I want UV, but when I run this bake, it is very fast and just paints a gradient over my output texture, not actually any base-colour.

Comment: The combined option should be the textures. The target material needs an image node with the target image, it does not need to be connected to other nodes, but it needs to be the selected node when you click bake.

Comment: Doesn't "combined" apply the shader? I'm trying to avoid shading and lighting, just base-color and alpha.
Thank-you for the hint on selected nodes... I'm now getting the result onto one texture without using Selected to Active.